# What is the significance of video card DeviceID from WMIC?

Tags: windows, batch, display-driver, wmic, hardware-detection

I'm using a batch script on Windows 10 to gather client hardware information. Some of my clients are laptops with dual video adapters, an embedded Intel graphics  adapter and a discrete Nvidia adapter.   I can gather the information I need from the output of:

```
wmic path win32_VideoController get /all /format:list
```

Some dual adapter clients report the Nvidia adapter as DeviceID=VideoController1 and the Intel adapter as DeviceID=VideoController2, while another laptop with identical hardware will report the Intel as VideoController1 and Nvidia as VideoController2.

I'm curious what the difference between two seemingly identical laptops could be.  Is there any significance of WMIC reporting an adapter as VideoController1 vs. VideoController2?

My question is: How does Windows choose which adapter will be VideoController1 or VideoController2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My Interpretation

According to [Win32_VideoController class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-videocontroller) the **DeviceID** property is inherited from [CIM_LogicalDevice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/cim-logicaldevice). Per [CIM_LogicalDevice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/cim-logicaldevice) it is suggested that it could "*represent a hardware entity that may or may not be in physical hardware*" and since [Standard WMI Qualifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/standard-wmi-qualifiers) indicates "*if the ID qualifiers are unintentionally omitted, the MOF compiler generates ID qualifiers automatically*"—to me this would imply that the DeviceID number you get back when running the `WMIC` command since it could just pick the ID automatically is not very significant.

### Supporting Resources

- > ### [**Win32_VideoController class**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-videocontroller)
  >
  > **DeviceID**
  >
  > Data type: **string**
  >
  > Access type: Read-only
  >
  > Qualifiers:
  >   [Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa392157(v=VS.85).aspx),
  >   [Override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa393650(v=VS.85).aspx)
  >   ("DeviceId"),
  >   [MappingStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa393650(v=VS.85).aspx)
  >   ("WMI")
  >
  > Identifier (unique to the computer system) for this video controller.
  >
  > This property is inherited from
  >   [CIM_LogicalDevice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/cim-logicaldevice).

---

- > ### [CIM_LogicalDevice class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/cim-logicaldevice)
  >
  > The **CIM_LogicalDevice class** represents a hardware entity that may
  >   or may not be realized in physical hardware.
  >
  > **DeviceID**
  >
  > Data type: string
  >
  > Access type: Read-only
  >
  > Qualifiers: [CIM_Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa393651)
  >
  > Address or other identifying information to uniquely name the logical
  >   device.

---

- > ### [Standard WMI Qualifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/standard-wmi-qualifiers)
  >
  > **ID**
  >
  > Data type: **VT_I4**
  >
  > Applies to: properties, parameters
  >
  > Uniquely identifies and sequences a property or method parameter when
  >   MOF statements are generated automatically.
  >
  > This qualifier is required for method parameters only. When creating
  >   parameters for a method, class designers should begin with Id(0) for
  >   the first parameter and use each successive integer for each
  >   successive parameter. If the ID qualifiers are unintentionally
  >   omitted, the MOF compiler generates ID qualifiers automatically.

Comment: @user2869128 Per my interpretation of my readings which I quote referenced for you explains how that is picked and how significant that ID number can be which seems to be not very significant at all since it can be picked automatically at times. I don't think that's very important based on these findings.

Comment: This meets my needs and I consider it answered.  Thank you!